# Maximum resolution of Nvidia Quadro 3000M 2GB

Tags: gpu, nvidia-graphics-card

Before I get a new monitor, I want to know the maximum resolution this mobile graphics card supports.

I found specs on this page, however no indication of the maximum resolution an external monitor would give.

https://www.techpowerup.com/gpu-specs/quadro-3000m.c1429

Comment: Your link tells you that it works fine for 1280x720, mediocre for 1366x768 and badly for 1600x900.

Comment: As the built in laptop monitor is using resolution 1920x1080 and using this card, I have to conclude that's not an exhaustive list.

Comment: The link is concerned with gaming. What is your Windows version?

Comment: You need to know what resolutions the *graphics card* supports, not just the chipset it's made with. The computer manufacturer's site would be best for that.

Comment: The resolutions supported will depend on the laptop configuration. Often (and "always" for contemporary laptop designs) the display connector is not directly connected to the GPU in a laptop design; while this enables dramatic power savings by using IGP for workloads that don't need a GPU it also prevents a "per GPU" list of resolutions from applying. To provide a specific answer you need to provide your laptop make and model number. Otherwise harrymc provided a answer that will enable you to find out the max resolution.

Answer (score 2):

## Finding Official Specifications Proves to be Hard

I was unable to find official spec sheets for this rather old GPU. [Even the official NVidia site, now archived, does not disclose this information and delegates the detailed specifications to the manufacturer.](https://web.archive.org/web/20110623040400/http://www.nvidia.com/page/quadrofx_go.html) Because of this, I have to infer most of my information from other, but similar hardware.

### The GF104 Family

The [NVidia Quadro 3000M 2GB](https://www.techpowerup.com/gpu-specs/quadro-3000m.c1429) uses a [GF104](https://www.techpowerup.com/gpu-specs/nvidia-gf104.g84) chip, which is the same chip NVidia used for the GTX 460 and its variants.

According to NVidia [the maximum digital resolution of the GTX 460 is 2560 × 1600 and the maximum VGA resolution is 2048 × 1536](https://web.archive.org/web/20110623032148/http://www.nvidia.com/object/product-geforce-gtx-460-us.html). Both are stated without refresh rate.

### Connectors

The GTX 400 Series apparently did not feature a DisplayPort connector, as even the flagship model, [the GTX 480 did not have one](https://web.archive.org/web/20110606125611/http://www.nvidia.com/object/product_geforce_gtx_480_us.html).

This leaves only (dual-link) DVI and HDMI as likely options, but it could be that the laptop's manufacturer implemented it on their own and professional cards are more likely to have newer ports with higher performance than consumer cards.

#### DVI

Dual-link DVI supports a maximum resolution of 2560 × 1600 @ 60 Hz or 1920 × 1080 @ 144 Hz. With single-link DVI only a maximum resolution of 1920 × 1080/1200 @ 60 Hz is possible.

#### HDMI

HDMI versions 1.3 to 1.4b support a [maximum resolution of 1920 × 1080 @ 144 Hz or 2560 × 1440 @ 75 Hz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI#Refresh_frequency_limits_for_standard_video).
Apparently, [even 1920 × 1080 @ 240 Hz and 2560 × 1440 @ 120/144 Hz are possible with 4:2:0 chroma subsampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI#Refresh_frequency_limits_for_standard_video).

#### DisplayPort

Should you have been lucky and your manufacturer implemented DisplayPort, it will likely have been [DisplayPort 1.2 with HBR or HBR2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayPort#Refresh_frequency_limits_for_standard_video) and will be limited by the cards maximum digital resolution of 2560 × 1440, but it might be able to push 85 Hz (HBR) or 165 Hz (HBR2) or push 1920 × 1080 @ 144 Hz (HBR)/240 Hz (HBR2).

### Conclusion

- Maximum VGA resolution: 2048 × 1536
- Maximum digital resolution: 2560 × 1440
- Maximum DVI resolution:

  - 2560 × 1600 @ 60 Hz
  - 1920 × 1080 @ 144 Hz
- Maximum HDMI resolution:

  - 2560 × 1440 @ 75 Hz
  - 1920 × 1080 @ 144 Hz
  - With Chroma Subsampling:

    - 2560 × 1440 @ 144 Hz
    - 1920 × 1080 @ 240 Hz
- DisplayPort 1.2 (unlikely):

  - HBR:

    - 2560 × 1440 @ 85 Hz
    - 1920 × 1080 @ 144 Hz
  - HBR2:

    - 2560 × 1440 @ 165 Hz
    - 1920 × 1080 @ 240 Hz

Results may vary, depending on the implementation of these transmission and display modes.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the resolutions supported by Windows with your current
monitor by entering *Settings > System > Display*, in the drop-down
list of "Display resolution".

You may see all the resolutions possible (or not possible) by clicking
"Display adapter Properties" and then clicking "List All Modes".

You may also force a custom resolution using the free
[Custom Resolution Utility (CRU)](https://www.monitortests.com/forum/Thread-Custom-Resolution-Utility-CRU)
(an old utility which probably still works).

Note that a real achievable/useful resolution depends on more factors
than just your graphic card, such as the CPU, motherboard, the port
and the usage that you wish to make of it (displaying text is
much less requiring than video or gaming).
The link in your question says that for gaming, this card
works fine for 1280x720, mediocre for 1366x768 and badly for 1600x900.